# xcode-select --install not running

Tags: macos, installation, xcode5

i try to install/update Xcode5 on OS X 10.9.1. to solve a problem with Homebrew. So i try:

```
    xcode-select --install
```

In forums/google they say it will start the installation eg. [here](http://www.computersnyou.com/2025/) but i get:

```
    Usage: xcode-select -print-path
    or: xcode-select -switch <xcode_folder_path>
    or: xcode-select -version
    Arguments:
    -print-path                     Prints the path of the current Xcode folder
    -switch <xcode_folder_path>     Sets the path for the current Xcode folder
    -version                        Prints xcode-select version information
```

Why? What is wrong?

thx for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Print your Xcode Path
`xcode-select -print-path`

If your Xcode path is not=`/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer`

change it in terminal

`sudo xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer`

Comment: Paste and run it terminal post the result here `ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/go/install)"`