# Cannot install command line tools due to out of date xcode-select

Tags: gcc, xcode5, osx-mavericks, gcc4

For weeks I've been trying to work this out.

When I run `bash install_script.sh` file as yt-project ( http://yt-project.org/#getyt ) instructs, it outputs this error:

```
gcc -fPIC -c blocksort.c

make: gcc: No such file or directory

make: *** [blocksort.o] Error 1
```

I got into contact with someone from the yt-users mailing list who had me check my version of xcode. I ran `xcode-select -version` and I recieve:

`xcode-select version 2003.`

This is definitely outdated.

I try to run `xcode-select --install` to ensure I have CLT, but it only feeds me back the menu of options to input into xcode-select. Nothing occurs.

I installed CLT directly from the developer website, as in Xcode 5.0 and later it is not in Preferences->Downloads. It seemed to install correctly, but it seems that Xcode itself installed incorrectly if I am unable to get a version number higher than 2003.

I tried uninstalling and reinstalling Xcode, but the problems did not change. As per [xcode-select --install not running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21365197/xcode-select-install-not-running) I checked the path on Xcode and it seemed correct. The output of `xcodebuild -version` is

`Error: Can't run /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcodebuild (no such file).`

I tried the command listed here [Can't install Command Line Tool, "xcode-select --install" doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20229437/cant-install-command-line-tool-xcode-select-install-doesnt-work) after confirming that I do not have a `/Library/Developer` folder.

The path for `xcode-select --print-path` is

`/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools`

When I do `gcc --version` it returns

`-bash: gcc: command not found`

How do I get the correct `xcode-select binary`?

I am very amateur at command line and there could be any number of assumptions that are incorrect that I fell into.

Thank you for your help!